# PY to APK using Kivy, Buildozer having issues

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivy-language, buildozer

I have a python file which uses Open CV and Aruco markers. The app works perfectly in the computer. However it is not opening in the android mobile.

1. In my buildozer requirements I have the following

   ```
   # (list) Application requirements
   # comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
   requirements = python3,kivy,numpy,opencv-python
   ```

it gives me the following error

```
    ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check OpenCV installation.
```

2. If I use the following as requirements

   ```
   # (list) Application requirements
   # comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
   requirements = python3,kivy,numpy,opencv
   ```

I am getting the following error:

```
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

I am stuck here. Could anyone help me out?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried few years ago opencv with kivy on android device and it worked fine. Did you try to specify the opencv version in buildozer.spec? For example: requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0,opencv==4.5.2,numpy

Comment: Thanks @NorbertTiborcz I tried with requirements = python3,kivy==2.1.0,numpy,opencv==4.6.0       I am getting ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check OpenCV installation.